# Blazor wait for ef core to finish request

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, blazor

So right now I get a

```
Error: System.InvalidOperationException: A second operation was started on this context before a previous operation completed.
```

Because blazor doesn't seem to respect the current request.

What I am doing is something like this:

FirstComponent.razor

```
@inject IService _service; // abstracted service that calls EF

<layout> // layout stuff here
  <SecondComponent /> // second blazor component
</layout>

@code {

  protected override async Task OnInitializeAsync()
  {
     var getSomething = await _service.OnInitializedAsync();
  }

}
```

SecondComponent.razor

```
@inject IService _service; // abstracted service that calls EF

@code {

  protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
  {
     var getSomething = await _service.GetSomething();
  }

}
```

---

So I split my entity in to multiple sub-components for editing it. Now I have one "parent" component that calls all these sub-components.

---

### Edit 1

My `IService` would look like this.

```
public interface IService
{
  public Task<Something> GetSomething();
}

internal class Service : IService
{
  private readonly SomethingRepository _repo;

  public Service(SomethingRepository repo)
  {
     _repo = repo;
  }

  public async Task<Something> GetSomething() => _repo.GetAsync();
}

internal SomethingRepository
{
  private readonly AppDbContext _context;

  public SomethingRepository(AppDbContext context)
  {
    _context = context;
  }

  public async Task<Something> GetAsync() => ...;//implementation of whatever
}
```

I am adding my `AppDbContext` to the service collection with `AddDbContext` and my services and repositories with `AddScoped`

Comment: It sounds like you have a design flaw with how you have set up your EF context. The problem will be in your service, it is not Blazor's fault. You cannot use the same instance of a context for more than one operation at a time. Proper dependency injection will ensure each request gets its own instance.

Comment: It is, reading the docs blazor does not support scopes at this time, like your API controller or MVC controller would. So my question is, how do I update blazor to make sure my components only call the database after another finished calling

Comment: Please show your service.

Comment: I'll edit my answer but I have a very big project so I'll try to abstract it but not leaving out core functionality.

Comment: If the service is using the same context instance between requests that will be a problem. [This is the preferred way](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/dbcontext-configuration/#dbcontext-in-dependency-injection-for-aspnet-core) to provide a context to the di system.

Comment: That edit doesn't help without knowing the lifetime scope of the context though I assume it is singleton based on your problem.

Comment: You nee the factory pattern here. [More precise link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/dbcontext-configuration/#using-a-dbcontext-factory-eg-for-blazor)

Comment: @Crowcoder it's scoped.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I've read about but that is just stupid... not that itself is stupid. But I have a very big application, got very excited on starting with blazor but I can't just change to this pattern because a big api (and other mvc cms) depend on my data layer

Comment: Use Blazor WebAssembly and get the data from your own API. The scopes in the API are free, just like in MVC.

Comment: I see you are using Blazor as Controllers (not using an API, but directly injecting services that under the hood use repository). 
Be careful from this: `scoped` in blazor behaves like `singleton`. [Blazor DI](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-5.0&pivots=server). I encountered this problem during my work. Read more on this topic as you will encounter problems later on for sure (not might, but will).
If you want to test it yourself, log the `DbContext's ContextId`: you will find that the same dbcontext will live like forever

Comment: I have the same problem, how did end up solving this?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Add this to your connection string "MultipleActiveResultSets=true"

Answer (score 5):

For Blazor Server apps you should not use the existing DI lifetimes for your DbContext.  Instead create a new one for each request, or scope it to a component.  per:

> EF Core provides the AddDbContext extension for ASP.NET Core apps that
> registers the context as a scoped service by default. In Blazor Server
> apps, scoped service registrations can be problematic because the
> instance is shared across components within the user's circuit.
> DbContext isn't thread safe and isn't designed for concurrent use. The
> existing lifetimes are inappropriate for these reasons:
>
> - Singleton shares state across all users of the app and leads to
>   inappropriate concurrent use.
> - Scoped (the default) poses a similar issue between components for the same user.
> - Transient results in a new instance per request; but as components can be long-lived, this results in a longer-lived context than may be
>   intended.
>
> The following recommendations are designed to provide a consistent
> approach to using EF Core in Blazor Server apps.
>
> - By default, consider using one context per operation.   . . .
> - Use a flag to prevent multiple concurrent operations:  . . .
> - For longer-lived operations that take advantage of EF Core's change tracking or concurrency control, scope the context to the lifetime of
>   the component.

[ASP.NET Core Blazor Server with Entity Framework Core (EFCore)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/blazor-server-ef-core?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In my case this is not a problem for a transient scope. I am not running a fully blazor server application. We are migration from MVC to blazor where some pages have been replaced with blazor functionality. I instantiate a component on some specific pages, so the lifetime is ended when user navigates away from the page.

Comment: Not even the answer .. odd how the voting works here

Answer (score -1):

Typically this happens when you use async/await in calling the service but do not use flags to stop the rendering of the child components. This should fix most of your "A second operation started..." issues.

```
<layout>
@if(_loading)
{
 <span> Loading .... </span>
}
else{
 <ChildComponent/>
}
</layout>


@code
{
  bool _loading;
  protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync(){
     _loading = true;
     var data = _service.getSomething();
     _loading = false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

So using the factory pattern provided by Henk Holterman is not a solution for me. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/dbcontext-configuration/#using-a-dbcontext-factory-eg-for-blazor

That did work is changing everythings lifetime from `Scoped` to `Transient`. Including the db context.

```
services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(..options.., ServiceLifetime.Transient);

services.AddTransient<IService, Service>();
services.AddTransient<SomethingRepository>();
```

Comment: But Transient services are not Disposed, are they?  You now depend on the GC for cleaning up, that won't scale well.

Comment: You are advised not to use the Transient DI lifetime, as it may get injected into a longer-lived service. You always Dispose your DbContext. If you create it manually, you use a using block, and if you scope/inject it to some other component, that component should be Disposable, and is responsible for Disposing when it is Disposed. You should never rely on GC. But by default a DbContext doesn't hold an open database connection, so it's not as dire as leaking a SqlConnection directly.