# How should I configure the Entity Framework Lifecycle for Blazor?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core, blazor, blazor-server-side, lifecycle

I'm developing a blazor application that makes extensive use of Entity Framework. I've done some reading that suggests the default lifecylce of a `DbContext` is not appropriate for Blazor (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/66817764/14024210). However, I do not intend to inject the context directly into my components, instead using a service into which the context is injected. As long as the context lives through the lifetime of my main form component, there should be no issues.

- Should I configure both the context and service as Transient? My understanding is this will provide a new instance of both whenever a component receives the context.
- Does my service need to implement `IDisposable` in order to be correctly disposed? Or is this not necessary if its only dependency is the `DbContext`?

In short, I want to correctly implement the "Unit of Work" concept that `DbContext` is design for.

Answer (score 1):

When you are using Blazor WebAssembly this resolves itself on the server: each API call has a perfectly usable lifetime to use as the Scope.

For Blazor server-side, managing a DbContexct with DI is simply [not appropriate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/blazor-server-ef-core?view=aspnetcore-5.0#database-access-5x).

The recommended approach is to create a DbContext for each operation, and manage it with a `using(...) {...}` block. You can inject a DbContextFactory to help with the configuration.

It could be tempting to use one DbContext per Component but this leads to Contexts staying open very long and increased memory use on the server. This won't scale well and doesn't encourage the use of services.

So, I would use one DbContext per Service method.

Comment: Thanks! This makes sense, but it also introduces a problem with disconnected entities. For example, I have an Employee object which is a child of my main model. Currently, the shared instance of DbContext allows this to be tracked. When I use a DbContextFactory, these entities are no longer attached to the context and it attempts to insert them. While I could always set their state to detached, this wouldn't be as clean. Alternatively, I could scope to the lifetime of the component and ensure the DbContext is disposed of appropriately.

Comment: Yes, that is convenient. But then your UI _is_ your DAL. You will pay the price in maintainability and testability. Detached entities (outside the data layer) are a lot cleaner imho.